# Magento js.js in magento/js/varien/ process time over 5s

Tags: magento

I am custom a theme base on base theme package.

But Why magento/js/varien/js.js process time over 5 seconds ,
when it process over the page appears.
sometimes it load just 200ms.
I install the magento in localhost.
My cache was disable.

When I Merge JavaScript Files it become normal

What cause this problem ?

Here is the screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaJ1R.png

Answer (score 0):

Your js.js loads in 11ms.
Check the Time Latency column.

Load time between 1-5sek on localhost without cache can be normal.
Depends on your view, amount of products or hardware.

Comment: It's not the loads time,I have only 5 products in my shop,If i change the default theme the page load time  will very fast in 200ms .if i change with my own theme , it will take over 5 seconds.